# sprite.add_internal(self) AttributeError: 'Alien' object has no attribute 'add_internal'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working through python crash course 3 building game , i have check multiple time I could not find any code error or any other error

is there I need to change in python library in my pc

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
from bullet import Bullet
from alien import Alien

class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behaviours."""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""

        pygame.init()
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)

        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
        self.ship = Ship(self)
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.aliens = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self._create_fleet()
        self.bg_color = (230,230,230)

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self.ship.update()
            self._update_bullets()
            self._update_screen()
            self.clock.tick(60)       
            
            # redraw the screen during each pass through the loop
    def _check_events(self):
                """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                           sys.exit()
                      elif event.type ==pygame.KEYDOWN:
                           self._check_keydown_events(event)

                      elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                           self._check_keyup_events(event)
    
    def _check_keydown_events(self,event):
        """ Respond to keypresses."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
             sys.exit()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
             self._fire_bullet()
             
    def _check_keyup_events(self,event):
        """Respond to key releases."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = False
    
    def _fire_bullet(self):
         """Create a new bullet and add it to the bullets group."""
         if len(self.bullets)< self.settings.bullets_allowed:
         
          new_bullet = Bullet(self)

          self.bullets.add(new_bullet)
            # # Move the ship to the right.
            # self.ship.rect.x += 1
    
    def _create_fleet(self):
        """Create the fleet of aliens."""

        # make an anien
        alien = Alien(self)
        self.aliens.add(alien)          
                
    def _update_screen(self):
         """Update images on the screen, and flip to the new screen."""
         self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color) 
         for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()
         self.ship.blitme()
         self.aliens.draw(self.screen)   
        # make the most recent drawn screen visible 
         pygame.display.flip()

    def _update_bullets(self):
         # Get rid of bullets that have disappeared.
         for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
            if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
                self.bullets.remove(bullet)
```

alien class

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Alien:
    """A class to represent a single alien in the fleet."""

    def __init__(self,ai_game):
        """Initialize the alien and set its starting point"""
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game.screen

    # load the alien image and set its rect attribute.

        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    # start the new alien near the top left of the screen

        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

    # store the alien's exact horizontal position
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
```

Comment: if __name__ =='__main__':
# make a game instance , and run the game.

 ai = AlienInvasion()
 ai.run_game()

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you have anything to add to the question - [edit] it. Don't use comments

Comment: when trying to edi i am getting erro on posting though i am created instance of AlienInvasion class and calling run_game using the instance if this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

`pygame.sprite.Group()` calls `add_internal` to all sprites that get added.

You need to make the Alien class inherit from Sprite.
It seems like Bullet is ok but I see that you import Sprite in Alien class but you don't use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot i somehow missed it thank again

Comment: No problems. ;)

Comment: @rockslusture If this answer helped, you can verify it to help future users, which gives the answerer some reputation.